# Nested self executing function java script throwing error for console.log()

Tags: javascript

Nested self executing function java script throwing error for console.log()
https://jsfiddle.net/vivek7189/co5oeqcg/

```
(function(a,b){
  console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)
   (function (a,b){
    console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)
   })(20,10)
})(30,40)
```

Comment: sometimes, javascript can't guess where to put a semicolon for you, and gets it wrong ... use semicolons correctly, and this sort of pain will go away ... basically js interprets this as `console.log('...')( ... )` ... and since console.log returns "undefined" and "undefined" is not a function, it fails ... there should be 4 `;` in your code - yo have none

Comment: @JaromandaX no need for 4 `;`, only for `console.log()` is enough..

Comment: I never said the code "needs" 4, I said there **should be 4** - even if you add the two you say are needed, javascript "pretends" another two are there as well ... oh, you can make the code run by adding a single `;` - or, by **shortening* the code by 1 character

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript engine treats

```
(function (a,b){
  console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b);
})
```

as an arguments for function call, because engine thinks that first `console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)` returns a function once you put something into parenthesis after that, but its not...
You have to make engine understand that you don't trying to call results of first `console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)` as a function, for example by adding `;` or even `+` (whatever) after first `console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)` so that engine understand that its two statements rather then one

Answer (score 0):

Consider this piece of code

```
function foo(a) {
    return function(b) {
        return a+b;
    }
}
```

You can run this like

```
var x = foo(2);
var y = x(3); // y == 5
```

but this can be done "shorthand" like

```
var x = foo(2)(3); // x == 5
```

in your code, you have

```
console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b);
  (function (a,b){
    console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b);
  })(20,10)
```

Without semicolons, javscript guesses wrong and thinks you are trying to do

```
console.log('')( ... )
```

you can make the code run in a few ways

minimal - add a single character to your code

```
(function(a,b){
    console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b); // add this colon
    (function (a,b){
        console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)
    }(20,10))
})(30,40)
```

make your code shorter

```
(function(a,b){
    console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)
    // use different syntax for the inner IIFE 
    // add a leading !, or +, or various other characters
    !function (a,b){
        console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b)
    }(20,10)
})(30,40)
```

> however, to avoid any pitfalls, put colons where they should be

```
v----- this one is optional, but may be required depending on preceding code
;(function(a,b){
    console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b); // here
    (function (a,b){
        console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b) // here
    }(20,10)); // here
})(30,40); // and here
```

Answer (score 0):

put `;` for `console.log()`

```
(function(a,b){
  console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b);
  (function (a,b){
    console.log("value a:"+a +" value b:"+b);
  })(20,10)
})(30,40)
```